# Thread doesn't seem to exit cleanly - thread hang

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

So I was trying to do some testing based off some things I know about the Java Memory Model (JMM) because I wanted to see how they applied to a initialization+assignment in a try-catch block with an exception thrown, and I obtained the results I wanted (not related, but I wanted to know if in a try-catch if the allocation could happen before the initialization, and in turn before some exception was thrown, could some other Thread see the uninitialized Object before the Exception was thrown - the answer seems to be no), however I encountered something odd related to my Thread running.

Basically, my Thread never seems to exit. I ran my code to completion in a debugger, and I can see the two Threads running. My main Thread being Thread, and the Thread I created Thread-1. After I complete the main method, my main Thread goes away and is replaced with DestroyJavaVM, as expected. However, Thread-1 seems to be waiting on something.

The part that really confuses me, other than the code being too simple to screw up, is that if I put a

```
System.out.print("");
```

inside of the while block, then the slow down caused by I/O seems to cause the Thread to "catch-up" on whatever it was doing, and see the interrupt. Another thing I noticed, is that if I put a breakpoint on the "finished" #println() statement, that the Thread will break on that line, and allow me to continue which causes the print statement in the standard-out, and the program exits. That doesn't make a lot of sense to me. What is happening behind the scenes that causes the created Thread not see the interrupt?

Here is the code I have for my testing, with the unimportant bits removed that were related to me testing the JMM:

```
public class Foo{
    static Foo p;

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                }
                System.out.println("finished");
            }

        });
        t.start();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
            try{
                p = new Foo();
            }catch(Exception pse){
            }
        }
        t.interrupt();
        System.out.println("main-method-completed");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Is it still reproducable for you if you run this exact code? Which JVM version are you runnig?

Comment: I can reproduce using java 1.6 update 12. I can't really try with another version at this moment, but I know it reproduces with that version. I think I have Java 7 update 55 (at least) at home, so I might try that a bit later.

Comment: In your catch you might want to try catching InterruptedException explicitly, and rethrowing that particular one. This is what gets thrown when a thread's execution has been interrupted and the required behavior is to either rethrow or interrupt the thread.

Comment: My understanding is that an InterruptedException is never thrown except from a blocking method, such as Thread#sleep(long). There shouldn't be an InterruptedException thrown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably reproduced the bug [JDK-6772683 : Thread.isInterrupted() fails to return true on multiprocessor PC](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6772683).

Comment: that looks pretty close to my code, and the description says it affects all versions 64-bit version 1.5 to 1.7, and since I'm on Windows 7, with a 64-bit JDK, it looks like you might be right. That's a good find, I would have never figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the thread runs its while-loop it won't get any messages from other threads in the system. If you do, for instance, `Thread.sleep(1);` the thread is paused, and a context switch to something else occurs. When the thread is restored, it will get the interrupt notification from some the main loop thread.

If you want to stop the loop in the thread you could either use a `volatile` variable (these are written and read explcitly from shared memory and are quite expensive), or use, for instance, an `java.util.conncurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean`, which at least in theory could use some less expensive method for communicate the its state between threads.

Comment: He's doing `t.interrupt()` which causes the check in the while loop to return false

Comment: Yes, but when I tried that last week it didn't work very well.

Comment: Well, when I look into the Thread.java (in jdk7) the `.interrupt` is synchronized, so it should work...

Comment: I'm not sure I like the "tried that last week it didn't work very well" without an explanation. I want to know why, not just that it doesn't work. I posted a question saying that something about it doesn't work, so I'm well aware already. EDIT: I'm using Java6, but its also synchronized there. EDIT2: Also, your answer doesn't answer my question, and to address your answer, using an AtomicBoolean is not necessary if only one Thread is ever writing to it. Any operation on a scalar less than an int is atomic anyway. The only benefit would be if two threads were writing to it simultaneously.

Comment: Well, you could start by test one of the three methods suggested above, and start debuggning from there, maybe? I also outlined a possible explanation that the thread didn't get a memory update from shared memory even though it should. You're welcome.

Comment: Regarding the AtomicBoolean, there are two threads running in the application above. One is the main loop started with `java Foo`, and the other one starts at the row `t.start();`. The operating system can put these on one or two CPU-cores.

Comment: The Thread.sleep(int) answer is related to me putting a System.out.print(String) - they both cause a slowdown, which I don't want. And if you think your answer addresses my question, then I suggest you revise it because I don't see a valid answer there. And as for the AtomicBoolean, it doesn't matter if the Threads are on separate cores or not, the operation is still atomic (barring volatile explanation). The only benefit is using AtomicBoolean#getAndSet(int, int) if two Threads are <b>writing</b> to the variable simultaneously. Only one Thread is writing to it, so AtomicBoolean is overkill.

Comment: Well, if someone writes to a variable, how can on be sure that someone else is reading the latest version of it? An ordinary boolean doesn't have that kind of guarantee in java. Most of this is written up very clearly in Brian Goetz Java Concurrency in Practice. I can really recommend it. Good luck.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. The loop had a single check inside of it, so, hypothetically, lets say I use a boolean. All it is doing is doing its single check, and then checking the static boolean to see if the other thread set it. Since the other thread setting it is atomic, I am guaranteed to see the latest data. The AtomicBoolean has no advantages in this situation. As I mentioned, the only advantage of any of the atomic classes for a primitive less than an int is if two threads are setting it simultaneously, which is because of the #getAndSet(boolean, boolean) method.